# missing vcl150.bpl

Tags: delphi, runtime

I have a delphi app which the author did not package the runtime library into it. It requires 3 bpls to run. I managed to find 2 of them but no matter where I go i could not find vcl150.bpl. I also tried insalling the delphi IDE(XE3). The IDE comes with vcl170.bpl and no vcl150.bpl. How do I slove this problem?

Comment: If You own license for XE3 than you're also entitled for XE - download and get it. But - there were an update for XE after release, it changed something in all those BPLs. You'd better get the BPLs be all of the same XE version and that should be version that compiled EXE.

Comment: Those Delphi BPL's are redistributable. Someone could make a Delphi XE application that consists of a form with a button, build it with packages and give it to you. I'm not sure that's going to be enough, maybe the application will ask for some other packages once those are supplied. I'd do it but I don't have Delphi XE.

Comment: @CosminPrund person told about "3 BPLs" - i guess he checked with dependancy walker before telling that.

Comment: Really not a programming question.  Off topic for this site, voted to close.  Needing a runtime file is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

vcl150.bpl is the VCL runtime package for Delphi XE. You should contact whoever supplied the application and ask for the necessary packages.

Comment: Or for monolithic no-BPL exe. However this looks more like the person find some abandonware and does not know who the author is and where to find him.

Comment: @Arioch'The Well, what do you suggest? The question asker needs to get the XE redist packages from somewhere? Will you supply them?

Comment: ISO XE-U1 can be downloaded from EMB site if one knows the URL (or if one is able to deduce it from XE3 download URL). If XE-U0 is available anywhere but pirates i dunno. Well, anyway he would need to get the license key, if he does not have already. Unless there is known way to unpack InstallAware archives (passworded 7zips). ///
I was glad to learn that there was only one update for XE though. Only 2 sets of BPl to try./// If topicstarter purchaased XE3 then he is okay, if he talks about XE3 trial he has - then he is in trouble.